# Jersey priority between path param queries and static path queries?

Tags: api, parameters, path, jersey

Let admit that with Jersey I expose 2 queries that are :

- /hello/{name}
- /hello/goodby

If the user do /hello/goodby, does Jersey guarantie that it is the request "/hello/goodby" that will be chosen and not "/hello/{name}" with the name equals to "goodby" ?

I have case like that in the services that I expose, it seems that static path is always chosen but I'm looking for a kind of confirmation in the documentation and I don't see anything here : https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to be in the documentation. It's going to be in the [JAX-RS Spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1508422880_d75cc0b95a462fb1ff9ff2ac78e1aa46). Look in the section "3.7.2 Request Matching", and somewhere along in the cryptic mumbo jumbo you will see this:

> Sort *E* using the number of literal characters in each member as the primary key

*E* being the so far qualified methods based on path. This means that the path with the most *literal characters* should be prioritized. In your case, that's why `/hello/goodbye` always wins. `goodbye` are literal characters, while `{name}` has *zero* literal characters, it's a *capture group*.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. /hello/goodby is given precedence over /hello/{name} assuming both are at the same level like class or method.

All matching classes are sorted in descending order on the below conditions -

1. Number of literal characters as primary key
2. Number of path params as secondary key
3. Number of regex strings as ternary key.

In your case, you have only literal characters and path params.

- /hello/goodby - 12 literal characters and 0 path params.
- /hello/{name} - 4 literal characters and 1 path params.

According to the sorting algorithm, /hello/goodby will be before /hello/{name},  and /hello/goodby is the best match.